# How to move linux distros without losing data

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-distributions

If I have these locations all on separate partitions:

- /usr
- /usr/local
- /opt
- /home

How can I remove Ubuntu (for example) and install Mint and lose no data? How would I preserve installed packages across the move?

Comment: I can't imagine it's a good idea to try this - you _might_ get away with it since Mint is so similar to Ubuntu, but I would not be surprised if you ended up with a broken system. You can certainly preserve your _data_ (as in, everything in /home), but expecting installed packages to work is probably unrealistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion, a safer way to achieve that would be to backup those directories and then re-install with the distribution of your choice.

If you want to backup your installed package list for re-installation later, you could try something like:

```
dpkg --get-selections > ~/Package.list
```

and then to restore the list later (on a debian based distro):

```
dpkg --set-selections < ~/Package.list
deselect
```

see https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc for more ideas.